# How to run all the tests on the same deal. Selenium Webdriver + Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm a newbie in automation testing. 
Currently doing a manual testing and trying to automate the process with Selenium Webdriver using Pyhton.
I'm creating a test suite which will run different scripts. Each script will be running tests on different functionality.
And I got stuck.
I'm working on financial web application. The initial scrip will create financial deal, and all other scripts will be testing different functionality on this deal.
I'm not sure how to handle this situation. Should I just pass the URL from the first script (newly created deal) into all other scripts in the suite, so all the tests were run on the same deal, and didn't create a new one for each test? How do I do this?
Or may be there is a better way to do this? 
Deeply appreciate any advise!!! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably you would have each test be able to run in isolation. If you have a way to create the deal through an API or Database rather than creating one through the UI, you could call that for each test. And, if possible, also clean up that data after your test runs.

If this is not possible, you could also record some data from a test in a database, `xml`, or `json` file. Then your following tests could read in that data to get what it needs to run the test. In this case it would be some reference to your financial deal.

The 2nd option is not ideal, but might be appropriate in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of approaches here that might help, and some of it depends on if you're using a framework, or just building from scratch using the selenium api.

1. Use setup and teardown methods at the suite or test level.

This is probably the easiest method, and close to what you asked in your post.  Every framework I've worked in supports some sort of setup and teardown method out of the box, and even if it doesn't, they're not hard to write.  In your case, you've got a script that calls each of the test cases, so just add a before() method at the beginning of the suite that creates the financial deal you're working on.

If you'd like a new deal made for each individual test, just put the before() method in the parent class of each test case so they inherit and run it with every case.

2. Use Custom Test Data

This is probably the better way to do this, but assumes you have db access or a good relationship with your dbm.  You generally don't want the success of one test case to rely on the success of another(what the first answer meant by isolaton).  If the creation of the document fails in some way, every single test downstream of that will fail as well, even though they're testing a different feature that might be working.  This results in a lot of lost coverage.

So, instead of creating a new financial document every time, speak to your DBM and see if it's possible to create a set of test data that either sits in your test db or is inserted at the beginning of the test suite.

This way you have 1 test that tests document creation, and X tests that verify it's functionality based on the test data, and those tests do not rely on each other.